# I/O error : Permission Denied(qbittorrent)

Tags: permissions, qbittorrent

I am downloading the files in `/media`. I do have the permission to folders and files, but for each torrent it is giving me this error.
Also, I disabled the hiberfile system of Windows so that I can delete or create folders in /media, which changed the Owner of files and folders in /media to root.
I then proceeded to edit the /etc/fstab to get the permissions back.
After all this, the error is still there.
I don't know how to proceed from here.

Qbitorrent version - 4.1.1 File system - NTFS OS - Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please post the version of qbt, your os system (with uname -a), and the filesystem type of /media (ntfs, exxt4, ..?)

Comment: Added the above information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `ls -l /media`? If you put the files in a sub-directory of `/media` please use that instead. It would also help if you explained how you run the Torrent client in question (i. e. as a regular application in your own user account or a system daemon). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I'd a similar problem and found a solution according [to this link.](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/2055)

Here is the note of aqeel13932:

> The real problem is I have a NTFS partition where my torrents located.
>   when it's mounted it usually take the name "New Volume" but when I was following the steps of sledgehammer999 mentioned I noticed that the in /media/[Username]/ there was two folders one called "New Volume" the other called "New Volume1" which represent my real partition
>   so what I just did:

- 1 - unmounted the partition.
- 2 - deleted the "New Volume" folder in "/media/[User]/"
- 3 - mounted my partition.
- 4 - recheck my torrents
  and it worked perfectly.

Hope this help others

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too and took forever to fix it. I'm just putting my fix here in case anyone else comes looking.

My situation may not be relevant for most. My setup is a 2011 laptop running proxmox. Qbittorrent is running in a Linux Mint virtual machine. The drive with permission errors was an 8tb external hard drive.

TL,DR - The drive's mounting location changed after I plugged in a second external drive. Removing that drive and rebooting fixed the problem.

The long version - The drive I couldn't access was an external drive. I plugged in a second external drive to copy some of the torrents off the device. I then rebooted and started facing the permission error.

It turns out that the drive I'd just plugged in took the other drive's mount point for some reason. Qbittorrent was trying to find the files but was looking on the wrong drive.

I removed the second drive, changed the first drive's mount point back to its proper location and rebooted.

The issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with qbittorrent on my TrueNAS Scale system. I made a dataset with a Samba share on it. I was trying to make qbittorrent write to that share but got this error. Turns out I forgot to set the "Share Type" to "SMB" while [creating the Dataset](https://www.truenas.com/docs/core/coretutorials/sharing/smb/#first-steps).